# Find all records with no associated records in db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models

```
class Checkout
 has_one :order
end

class Order 
  belongs_to :checkout
end
```

I need to find all checkouts that has no order yet. How can I do it with rails?

Comment: `Checkout.includes(:order).where(orders: { id: nil })` can list them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`left outer join`](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html) that would give you all checkouts joined with orders. Then select rows without orders (`order.id == nil`)

```
Chceckout.left_outer_join(:orders).where('orders.id' => nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that includes() expects the name of the association but the where expects the name of the table. For a has_one the association will generally be expressed in the singular, so that changes, but the where() part stays as it is.So  statement would be:

```
  Checkout.includes(:order).where( :orders=> { :orders_id=> nil } )
```

Comment: `where( :orders=> { :orders_id=> nil } )` will query like `.where('orders.order_id IS NULL)`  in SQL which leads to wrong answer.